# Firebase RemoteConfig Conditions General validation error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

When trying to publish a new condition into Firebase i get Error stating A general validation error occured and nothing else. The condition is defined as App=iOS and AudienceGroup=X_Audience. I have tried changing rule to include other audiences and same error. The only thing i can think of is your not allowed to use Audience and App name inside a condition. Let me know if anyone else has experienced this.[image]

Comment: [Answer] Make Sure when you remove an audience you also remove it from conditions that might also use it otherwise it will not save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make Sure you remove any mentions of deleted Audiences from conditions others wise it will not save and will get a validation error.